# Could a leaking boiler be fixed?

Tags: hvac, heating, boiler

I'm having a leaking hole in the cast iron boiler tube so does it mean that its time for a new  boiler or is there any way it could be permanently fixed?

Comment: If you have one hole, you might want to make sure you don't almost have *many* holes. Cast iron does not usually develop leaks without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

It was built, so therefore it can be fixed or re-built. But, can you even get just that part or portion of assembly? Can you find someone to weld the hole shut? Both very doubtful, but absolutely worth a shot. Although, definitely get an HVAC person or firm in to let you know for sure. They have access that the public doesn't. However, this may very well be just a symptom of a failing & rotting boiler, so replacement may be the only real or long-term course of action.

Comment: what is the name and model of the boiler?